# Noun for a non urgent task you have been meaning to do for a long time but have not got around to?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I don't mean procrastination or words like that. I'd like a noun, but I doubt it exists. An adjective will do as well. Ideally it would fit in a sentence like: "He was caught up in the mood of ____".

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how your sample sentence would end with a word meaning _a non-urgent task you have been meaning to do for a long time but have not got around to_.

Comment: @KillingTime Well, they have been meaning to get around to doing an  edit, but...